# How prove prove the identity $J_{t}=J\triangledown\cdot V$

Tags: differential-geometry

prove the identity
$$J_{t}=J\triangledown\cdot V$$
where $J=\begin{vmatrix}
x_{u}&x_{v}\\
y_{u}&y_{v}
\end{vmatrix}$ 
is the Jacobian of the map $x(u,v;t)\in R^2$ and 
$$V(x)=x_{t}$$

Comment: Is this homework? http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9180/proposal-ban-verbatim-homework-questions-which-have-no-accompanying-text?cb=1

Comment: No,my frend @Matt ,This is my frend ask me.Thank you